# Where should I put web application code in the file-system hierarchy

Tags: linux, webserver, directory-structure, fhs

What would be the most FHS compliant and standard location for putting the source code of a web-app, let's say a Flask app, be? I've looked around and haven't found any definitive and satisfactory answer yet.

Edit :: Just to clarify, this is at the time of deployment, not development. So the source code will be served by something like `gunicorn`.

Comment: You mean on the server?

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask, in which directory of the server should I put it in?

Comment: I'd put in `/opt`.

Comment: Source code should be in your home directory, wherever you keep your development work.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor But I'm not talking about a development machine, I'm talking about deployment. Check the edit I made to the question.

Comment: `/opt` or `/var`. Just to give you an example, default installation of Apache uses `/var/www/html` for serving pages.

Comment: "location for putting the **source code**" -- did you mean source code.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes I did mean source code, specifically `.py` files. For example a flask application, which is nothing but a directory containing `.py` files. I'm not talking about static content that can directly be served by HTTP. That's why I said web-app and web-application source code.

Comment: @GMaster I see. Well, I've seen people say that the default location for apache doesn't make much sense [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) wise. The FHS says that `/var/` should be used for files that change frequently. `/opt/` could be a better contender, the FHS says that it should be used for locally installed software.

Comment: Here's a reference btw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `/opt/` seems like a good option to me too, but still, can you give some explanation for your choice?

Comment: How about defaulting to `/opt` but asking the end user where they'd like it? (I prefer `/usr/local/app/`, for example.)

Comment: @SkullTech: `/opt` is a place where standalone software packages go, it's also described as such in FHS. Some distros, Slackware for example puts big programs that come with their own set of shared libraries and stuff in `/opt`.